# How to generate a CREATE script for several tables in pgAdmin III?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin, phppgadmin

In pgAdmin III you can:

- right-click a table;
- scripts;
- CREATE script;
- save the script from the SQL Editor.

If one has to do this for more than one table, is there a way to combine the scripts in one file (apart from manually copy-pasting them)? If this can be done via psql prompt or phppgadmin, that will be ok too.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a way using pgAdmin.

- Right-click on your database (or schema).
- Choose "backup"
- Under "Format" choose "plain"
- Under "Dump Options #1" choose "Only schema"
- Under "Objects" choose the tables you want.

Then click "backup". The output should be a plain text file with the create table statements.

[Here's](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22.2/backup.html) the PgAdmin documentation on backup.

Comment: Do you know the updated procedure for pgAdmin 4?

Comment: The other answer here using pgdump will get you what you need. I don't know how to do this in pgadmin 4.

Comment: For those who stumble in this thread but want to have a CREATE statement but also INSERTs to fill it with data, do a "Backup" -> "Format: Plain" like in answer, but don't choose "Only schema",  in Table Options choose "Use Column INSERTS" and then press Backup.

Comment: And regarding @sw1337 question - as I see in pgAdmin 4 there is the choice "Only schemas" in Data Options tab in Backup window, so maybe that's it.

Answer (score 6):

["pg_dump"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html) is also an option here. The `-s` flag for schema-only and `-t` to select specific tables. It's not `psql` or `pgAdmin` though. It's a utility available to the PostgreSQL user.
Example:

```
sudo su - postgres
pg_dump -s database
```