# Is there a way to generate CREATE statement for pk/fk constraints in progresql programmatically

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716760/how-to-generate-a-create-script-for-several-tables-in-pgadmin-iii) is an example of how to generate CREATE statement from pgAdminIII.  But is there a way to generate this programmatically in plpgsql?  What I mean is, is there a convenient function that generates this for me?

Comment: The linked-to topic does the equivalent of `pg_dump --schema-only mydb > mydb.out`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will create the statements to create the current primary key and foreign key constraints:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
'ALTER TABLE '||schema_from.nspname||'.'||table_from.relname||' 
 ADD CONSTRAINT "'||const.conname||'" '||
 pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef (const.oid, true)||';' as add_constraint
FROM pg_constraint const
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace schema_from ON (const.connamespace = schema_from.oid)
LEFT JOIN pg_class table_from ON (const.conrelid = table_from.oid)
WHERE const.contype in ('f','p') --foreign key, primary key
;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was seeing if there was some other existing stored proc or function that did this.  :)